# Which sefer did Pinchas Finish writing?

Tags: history, riddle, jewish-books

Which sefer did Pinchas Finish writing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gemara in BAVA BASRA 15 says that Yeshouah wrote Sefer Yeshouah and Pinchas finished it.

Comment: Or to be more precise: Yehoshua wrote the whole book up to (and including) 24:28, Elazar continued with verses 29-32, and Pinchas wrote verse 33.